# How to describe word formatting changes automatically and unexpectedly?

Tags: word-request

How to describe word formatting changes automatically and unexpectedly? Sometimes when we use another PC to open a word file, formatting changes automatically and unexpectedly due to word version difference. How do describe this automatic and unexpected change? Like formatting is off?

Comment: There is a Japanese word that has been adopted into English: [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), for the specific case where a character set is misinterpreted. For example, when an accented character like **á** gets turned into something nonsensical like � throughout the entire document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is a bad thing.  I'd say that the document is (or has been) messed up.

> Did you get my resume?
> Yes, but I had trouble reading it. It was all messed up.
> Oh no, what was the problem?
> I think you must have used a special font that I don't have.